# How does iteration work in Hashset?

Tags: java

I just stumbled upon this  statement about the **java.util.HashSet** and it goes "*This class makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.*" Can any one explain the statement?
Statement Source: [click here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_hashset.htm)

Comment: @YassinHajaj Javadoc.

Comment: It means that when you use iterators for HashSet and in this HashSet you have got 3 sets, then in one iteraton order for returning sets will be first, second, third and another time it may be second,third,first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashSet` is using *N* buckets and stores the elements based on their hashcode in one of these buckets to make searching faster: when you search for an element, the set calculates the hash of the element to know which bucket it needs to search, then it checks if that bucket contains this element. This makes searching *N* times faster since the set doesn't need to check the other *N-1* buckets.

For a small number of elements, the number of buckets can be small. But with more elements arriving, the buckets will start to contain more elements which means that searching will go slower. To solve this problem, the set will need to add more buckets and rearrange its elements to use the new buckets.

Now when we iterate over a `HashSet` we do it by starting with the elements from the first bucket, then from the second bucket and so on. You see that `Set`s which are using only buckets can't guarantee the same order of elements since the buckets can change between iterations.

Comment: In Java 8 HotSpot, HashMap#put was improved to support more elements and rebucket using `TreeNode` rather than the linked list using `Node` to avoid this slowliness when adding/searching elements.

Comment: True, but I tried not to focus on internals on buckets but on general idea behind lack of guarantee of elements order.

Comment: @brimborium Thanks for edit. My English is very far from perfect so I am grateful for your corrections. I edited first paragraph so it would be nice if you could take a look at it one more time :)

Comment: So whenever an element is added the hash value is recalculated, hence the change in order of the set right? correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Pshemo English is not my native language either, but I will have a look at it. :)

Comment: @comeunglued7 It is not as much as *whenever an element is added* but more like whenever buckets are not balanced enough to make searching reasonably fast.

Answer (score 3):

It basically means a `HashSet` has no order. Then you should not rely on values order in your code.

If your set contains values `{2, 1, 3}` (insert order), nothing guarantees that iterating over it will return `{2, 1, 3}` nor `{1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: if you put three entries and iterate over them twice, you'll get the same order both times.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Yes, that is true. But it is a special case. Any call on the `Hashset` might change the order. So it is saver to assume that order is not guaranteed ever.

Comment: So whenever an element is added the hash value is recalculated, hence the change in order of the set right? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Just because iteration order is not changing in one special case is not a guarantee of order being consistent in all cases. At the time HashMap re-sizes order can change very easily.

Comment: @akhil_mittal it *may*, but it doesn't happen *every time*, how one can believe reading the first version of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because `HashSet` is not ordered, the iterator probably walks all buckets and steps through each bucket's contents in turn. This means that if more items are added so that the buckets are rebalanced then the order can change .

E.g. if you have `1`,`2`,`3` and you iterate you may well get `1`,`3`,`2`. Also, if you later add `4` you could then get `4`,`2`,`3`,`1` or any other order.

Comment: The previous order will be maintained. The fact you add a new element doesn't mean it will rebucket all its elements. If you find it hard to believe, then test it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I deliberately changed the original order too because adding the `4` *could* have caused a rebalance of the buckets and therefore a complete change in order, even of the old items.

Comment: Rebucket happens when the inner `HashMap` has many elements and converts the nodes into `TreeNode`s. For this case, that won't happen. See the source code of `HashMap#put`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - See the call to `resize` in [addEntry](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.addEntry%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cint%29) when buckets exceeds `threshold` - it extends the bucket array and transfers all existing entries into it - this could easily change the order of **all** entries.

Comment: That's OpenJDK 6 which is outdated nowadays. I'm talking about Java 8.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - There's still a call to `resize` in the [Java 8](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.putVal%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29) one.